# How to get country code and phone number separately and validate length of the ph number based on country code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I installed these libraries in my project to get Country code. This is not validating Phone number based on country code. I need one more feature in this.

How to get country code and phone number separately? Right now it's getting them together - for example: +917894568978.

1. `ngx-international-phone-number`
2. `google-libphonenumber`

Requirement:

- Country code: +91
- Phone number: 7894568978

And it should validate based on country code. Can you help me?

HTML:

```
<international-phone-number 
     [(ngModel)]="model.phone_number" placeholder="Enter phone number" 
     [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
     [maxlength]="20" [defaultCountry]="'in'" [required]="true" 
     #phoneNumber="ngModel" 
     name="phone_number">
</international-phone-number>
```

Component.ts:

```
phone_number: any;
console.log(phone_number) // +919567894568
```

Comment: Sounds like a lot of work, especially since neither the country codes have a set length (1 to 3 digits) and some countries don't even have a "simple rule" for their internal numbers. In Germany you can almost have any length of valid numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Installed these two libraries.
1) "ngx-mat-intl-tel-input": "^3.0.0",
2) "libphonenumber-js": "^1.7.51"
it works perfectly for me.. I can able to get dialCode and phone number seperatly in this library.And its validating length also..